# Excel VBA - parse JSON string and set cell values based on key:values

Tags: arrays, json, excel, vba, parsing

I have an Excel spreadsheet with columns:

```
    |      A     |    B   |      C     |      D     |
    | Job number | Status | Actual Hrs | % Complete |
1___|____________|________|____________|____________|
2___|____________|________|____________|____________|
```

I have a macro to obtain the following string from an external web API:

```
[{
  "jobnumber":"123",
  "status":"Active",
  "actualhrs":"133",
  "completion":"94"},
{
  "jobnumber":"124",
  "status":"Active",
  "actualhrs":"13",
  "completion":"5"},
  ...
]
```

The string will contain hundreds of jobs. I am stumped trying to parse the response as an object in ExcelVBA to then populate rows in a spreadsheet.

Does anyone have any pointers for me? I realise I haven't got any VBA code shown, but to be honest I'm going in circles.

I have tried Dim data as Object.
For each loop through the object.

Comment: JSON-VBA is a great tool to parse json data. https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON . You can also extract data with VBA `Split` or `RegExp`.

Answer (score 1):

- Download `JsonConverter.bas` from https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON
- Import `JsonConverter.bas` into the workbook
- Add `Scripting` reference (VBE Tools>Reference, check `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`)
- Store all JSON data in an array and write the output to the sheet all at once to improve efficiency

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub JsonData()
    Dim jsonStr As String, oJson, vKey
    Dim JsonParse As Object
    Dim iR As Long, iC As Long, arrRes()
    jsonStr = [a1] ' JSON string, modify as needed
    Set JsonParse = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonStr)
    If Not JsonParse Is Nothing Then
        ReDim arrRes(JsonParse.Count, 1 To JsonParse(1).Count)
        iR = 0
        iC = 0
        For Each vKey In Split("Job number|Status|Actual Hrs|% Complete", "|")
            iC = iC + 1
            arrRes(iR, iC) = vKey
        Next
        For Each oJson In JsonParse
            iC = 0
            iR = iR + 1
            For Each vKey In oJson
                iC = iC + 1
                arrRes(iR, iC) = oJson(vKey)
            Next
        Next
        Sheets.Add
        Range("A1").Resize(iR + 1, iC).Value = arrRes
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

---

- A pure VBA way to parse json data
- *Note:*
  The code may lead to a runtime error if the JSON data is invalid due to the absence of JSON validation.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub JsonData2()
    Dim jsonStr As String
    Dim iR As Long, iC As Long, arrRes()
    Dim aData, vItem, vKey, vJson
    ' Remove space, newline, header and trailer chars
    jsonStr = Replace(Replace([a1], Chr(10), ""), Chr(32), "")
    jsonStr = Replace(Mid(jsonStr, 3, Len(jsonStr) - 4), Chr(34), "")
    ' Split json data
    aData = Split(jsonStr, "},{")
    ReDim arrRes(UBound(aData) + 1, 1 To 4)
    iR = 0
    iC = 0
    ' Populate header
    For Each vKey In Split("Job number|Status|Actual Hrs|% Complete", "|")
        iC = iC + 1
        arrRes(iR, iC) = vKey
    Next
    ' Extract json data
    For Each vJson In aData
        iR = iR + 1
        iC = 0
        For Each vItem In Split(vJson, ",")
            iC = iC + 1
            arrRes(iR, iC) = Split(vItem, ":")(1)
        Next
    Next
    ' Write output to sheet
    Sheets.Add
    Range("A1").Resize(iR + 1, iC).Value = arrRes
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [VBA-JSON](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON). Here is sample code:

```
Sub ParseJSONAndPopulateSheet()
    ' Declare variables
    Dim json As String
    Dim jsonObj As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim jobData As Object
    Dim rowData As Variant
    
    ' Replace this with your actual JSON string received from the API
    json = "[{""jobnumber"":""123"",""status"":""Active"",""actualhrs"":""133"",""completion"":""94""},{""jobnumber"":""124"",""status"":""Active"",""actualhrs"":""13"",""completion"":""5""}]"
    
    ' Parse JSON string to object
    Set jsonObj = JsonConverter.ParseJson(json)
    
    ' Loop through each object in the JSON array
    For i = 1 To jsonObj.Count
        Set jobData = jsonObj(i)
        
        ' Get job data
        rowData = Array(jobData("jobnumber"), jobData("status"), jobData("actualhrs"), jobData("completion"))
        
        ' Populate spreadsheet with job data
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Replace "Sheet1" with your sheet name
            .Cells(i + 1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(rowData) + 1).Value = rowData
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Here is the sample output from above code:

[image]

Notes:
Don't forget to check [Installation Guide](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON#installation)